# Не проходит запрос к БД при авторизации PHP + MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, авторизация

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: не проходит запрос БД. Данные получаю с форм посредством AJAX (запаковываю в JSON и отправляю на сервер). Далее, используя PDO в PHP подключаюсь к MSSQL, где находится БД. На сервер данные приходят, а к БД запрос не выполняется.

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=WIN-H0CPAVNR2UI\SQLEXPRESS;Database=UsersForProject");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Couldn't connect to the database".$e->getMessage());
}

$user = json_decode($_REQUEST['user']);

$user->password = hash('md5', $user->password);


$query = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Login = '".$user->login."' AND Password = '".$user->password."'") or die("Query error");
var_dump($query);
if ($query==1) {
   $cookie_name = $user->login;
   $cookie_value = $user->password;
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 3600);
}?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать. Пытался использовать одинарные кавычки для переменных и функцию query(), которая возвращает строку запроса.

Comment: это `PDO` вам мстит за такое его использование

Comment: запрос может и выполняется, но вряд ли проходит проверку `$query==1`, по-хорошему бы выводить ошибки синтаксиса базы данных. Юзер выше намекает на http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php в нынешние времена формирование запроса как у вас не практикуется.

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил использованием функции prepare()

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Login = ? AND Password = ? ') or die("Query error");
$query->execute(array($user->login, $user->password));
$res = $query->fetchAll();

if ($user->login == $res[0][1] && $user->password == $res[0][3]) {
   $cookie_name = $user->login;
   $cookie_value = $user->password;
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 3600);
}
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: ухты ж ё моё, я и не думал, что такое может быть! Человеку дали ссылку всего-лишь на одну функцию - prepare - а он сам разобрался и всё сделал. Чувак, ты вернул мне веру в человечество.